# Configuring iMac 2023 to use Google LDAP Configuration but cannot connect

Tags: macos, imac, ldap

I am setting up a series of new iMacs 24 inch 2023 models to use Google LDAP in a classroom setting. I have gone through the directions that Google provide as well as Apple on adding LDAP to the users and groups but have run into a very confusing problem:

On the screen where network servers is listed it shows a red icon indicating it cannot connect to ldap.google.com. When I look further at the settings, and open the Directory Utility and click edit on the Google LDAP configuration, it shows the custom option is unchecked.

[image: Google Secure LDAP dialog]

I will click ok and then do the mandatory reboot and when I come back it is changed again or the option is unselected.

[image: Users & Groups - Login Options]

Has anyone run into this issue or have a way to get around it?